# How to remove quotation from a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have like this array in my code:

```
x = ['"google"','"facebook"',"youtube"]
```

I want the output will be like this

```
["google","facebook","youtube"]
```

how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.strip` and a list comprehension

```
In [1062]: x = ['"google"','"facebook"',"youtube"]

In [1063]: [i.strip('"') for i in x]
Out[1063]: ['google', 'facebook', 'youtube']
```

Alternatively, you could use `map` instead of a list comprehension

```
In [1065]: list(map(lambda i: i.strip('"'), x))
Out[1065]: ['google', 'facebook', 'youtube']
```

You can also use `str.replace`

```
In [1074]: [i.replace('"', '') for i in x]
Out[1074]: ['google', 'facebook', 'youtube']
```

Comparing all three, the list comprehension with `str.strip` is the fastest

```
In [1066]: %timeit([i.strip('"') for i in x])
The slowest run took 12.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 805 ns per loop

In [1067]: %timeit(list(map(lambda i: i.strip('"'), x)))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 µs per loop

In [1075]: %timeit([i.replace('"', '') for i in x])
The slowest run took 5.48 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 975 ns per loop
```